# How to convert pandas.core.series.Series object with Multiple index to a pandas Dataframe with all columns filled?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I Have one pandas series with multiple index like this image "target","Lastnewjob", "experienceGroup".
this is pandas.core.series.series type. I want to convert it to a dataframe(second image) where "experienceGroup" values will be column names and "target","Lastnewjob" remains as columns.

[image]

Dataframe that I want to see

[image]

Code to get the series by using groupby.

```
Job=df.groupby(['target','last_new_job'])['experienceGroup'].value_counts()
Job.unstack()
```

-- Pandas series

Adding more details So that you can create the Job- pandas series actually resulted from groupBy and value_counts()

```
details={
"experienceGroup":['0-5','6-12','13-19','20 & above','0-5','6-12','13-19','20 & above'],
"last_new_job":[1,'>4',2,"never",4,3,3,4],
"target":[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0],
"experience":[1,7,15,20,3,8,17,25]  }   
 df5 = pd.DataFrame(details) 
 df5
```

To create Pandas series and display it by unstacking- use the below code

```
Job=df5.groupby(['target','last_new_job'])['experienceGroup'].value_counts()
Job.unstack()
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index

You can also use reset_index with MultiIndex.

Comment: @mustnot thanks for your suggestion. But i could not do it. I tried those option. I have updated my question. to create DF and pandas series . Could you please give it a second try. Thanks.

Comment: can you try this? Job.unstack().reset_index()
i write below @BLimitless answer comments about your Series.reset_index ValueError

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't tell if the comment answered the question in enough detail for you, though @mustnot is right you can use reset_index. Here's my code to recreate your dataframe, and then the solution:

```
arrays = [
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
   [1,2,3,4,'>4','never',1,2,3,4,'>4','never']
]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
experienceGroup = {
    '0-5': [2127, 535, 152, 87, 87, 1068, 1146, 278, 61, 52, 40, 500],
    '6-12': [2172, 833, 292, 323, 572, 411, 653, 282, 89, 94, 171, 194],
    '13-19': [911, 444, 184, 201, 711, 109, 169, 59, 51, 45, 160, 31],
    '20 & above': [693, 386, 164, 190, 1317, 118, 148, 80, 30, 36, 225, 13],    
}
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['target', 'last_new_job'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=experienceGroup, index=index)
df
```

Then my data frame looks like your multi index:

[image]

To remove the multi-index, all you need to do is:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

Then you get the single index dataframe you're looking for:

[image]

If this answers your question please accept so everyone knows this has been answered, and otherwise let us know if you're still struggling so we can help out!

Comment: Thank you for trying it out.This I have tried. It is not the solution. Could you please try once more. Here is small difference I am going to explain now. My variable "Job" is not a dataframe. it is pandas series with multi index and you can notice your Multi-index DF and My JOB, experienceGroup is present above lastnewJob columnname(not in ur DF but in JOB). I tried resetindex() i got error : ValueError: cannot insert experienceGroup, already exists ------------- I got this error as I tried it . in your df creation you have handled experienceGroup

Comment: Got it. Does [this page](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html) have what you need? Midway through it talks about converting a multi-index series to dataframe. You could play around with the re-index method.

Comment: @IpsitaDash says exeception means in the following situations
Job.name in Job.index list ("experienceGroup" in ['target', 'last_new_job', 'experienceGroup'])

Comment: @IpsitaDash, you could try converting the series to a DataFrame. Calling [.to_frame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) on the series might do the trick. Let us know.

Comment: @BLimitless thank you. your suggestion worked.I have upvoted. A small change was needed to handlied categoricalIndex column . But your link was very helpful.

Comment: @IpsitaDash excellent! glad to be helpful. Have a great weekend. Also, could you mark the answer accepted so the community knows this is closed?

Answer (score 0):

**I Have solved the multi Indexing and Categorical Index for column to have the desired results. **

1. created a pandas.series object by using groupby().Value_counts()
2. Used pd.series() object .Unstack() to save it as DataFrame.
3. Obtained data frame has multi index and column as Categorical Index.
4. Now convert the Categorical column index to list
5. Now use reset index on the dataframe
   Codes :

   #step 2
   Job=df5.groupby(['target','last_new_job'])['experienceGroup'].value_counts().unstack()
   #step 4
   Job.columns=Job.columns.tolist()
   #step 5
   Job.reset_index(inplace=True)
   Job
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NKJH.png)